# Pandas dataframe - how to calculate the difference of end and start values for a list of items

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

The task is to create a function that takes in two inputs (1) a list (2) the start date of calculation. The output is to create a function that generates a list of the names of highest 10 values based on percentage return.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

#Stocks.xlsx contains the field "Stock Code"
stock_list = pd.read_excel("Stocks.xlsx")
stock_code_List = stock_list["Stock code"]

start_date = "2019-01-01"

def top_10_stocks (start_date,stock_code):
    for i in stock_code:
       yf.download("IBM",start_date)["Close"]
    print(i)

    %Gain_Loss = ((df.iloc[-1]-df.iloc[0])/df.iloc[0])*100

    sort_value = %Gain_Lost.sort()
```

This is where I got stuck.

Comment: You have the metric for each stock.  You know how to sort a DF on a given column, as that is in any PANDAS tutorial.  You know how to extract the first N rows of a DF, as that is also in the tutorials.  How are  you stuck?

Comment: sorry, I get the individual logic of how to get the closing price of one stock from yfinance and the % return calculation for a single stock but don't know how to fit it all together. Firstly, I'm stuck with the for loop that will get the closing data for "all" the stock codes in my list. Secondly, how do I get the %Gain_Loss value of individual stocks, put them in order and extract only the top five stocks. I'm new to programming so not good at this. Many Thanks.

Comment: There's the fundamental problem: "I'm new to programming".  [Where do I start]( https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) is not a valid question here; it is not focused enough.  You're on the wrong site for general tutorial help.